# z-index issues with Div boxes

Tags: css

Hi when I'm hovering on I want the box to flip 180 and stay z-index'd on top of the boxes behind them. How do I achieve this in order to display on top I set the z-index in hover to 100 but as soon as I hover off it goes behind the boxes. I have tried transition delay as well and I'm still getting the same issue. Can someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

.boxfront {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container {
display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition-property: transform, z-index;
  transition-duration: 2s, 10s;
  transition-delay:0s,0s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;



}

.container:hover  {
  transform: scale(2, 2) rotateY(180deg);
z-index: 100;



}






</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxfront"></div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxfront"></div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxfront"></div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxfront"></div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxfront"></div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxfront"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you screenshot what you exactly want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container {
  z-index: 100;
}

.container:hover  {
  z-index: 200;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uop6ehac/